# Oracle MCS-Storage

Tags: oracle, storage, oracle-maf, mcs

I have created a storage collection in Oracle MCS. I can access collection using the roles assigned ,but I want to know whether is it possible to access this collection as "anonymous user(without credentials)" in oracle maf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storage does not yet support anonymous access. So the answer to the question is no.

Frank